# How to get an entity in marionette.js using an existing backend service?

Tags: marionette

Suppose I have the following entity:

```
MyApp.module('Entities', function(Entities, MyApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
Entities.SomeEntity = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var API = {
    getSomeEntity: function(someEntityId) {
        // What goes here?
    }
};

MyApp.reqres.setHandler("someEntity:entities", function(someEntityId) {
    return API.getSomeEntity(someEntityId);
});
});
```

And suppose I have a backend service /getInfo?id= which returns a JSON object {foo: "bar"}.

Question:
1) What should I place in the API.getSomeEntity method?
2) How to make it asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Backbone considers that if a model has a non-null `id` attribute, it exists on the remote API. And if you call `fetch` on that model instance, it will contact the API requesting the data. So you'd do something like this:

```
getSomeEntity: function(someEntityId) {
    var myModel = new Entities.SomeEntity({id: someEntityId});
    myModel.fetch();
    return myModel;
}
```

Since you're using a non-standard API, you'll need to define your API endpoint also:

```
Entities.SomeEntity = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function(){
        return "/getInfo?id=" + this.get('id');
    }
});
```

As to your last question: Backbone fetches the data asynchronously by default/design.

Comment: What about if the service returns a JSON object (ie {foo: "bar"}) and I want to "massage" it to make the Model contain different attributes (ie Model.set("name", returnedObject.foo))?

Comment: To "massage" the received data, you need to define the "parse" method on your model, and to modify the JSON that gets sent to the API rewrite Backbone.sync.